# Writing strings to standard input in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to automate a startup of a specific service with bash

When the service is started with init.d (/etc/init.d/openvpn.custom) it is promting for username  and then password  - and then it connects

The auth-user-pass from-file is not possible with the installed version, and it cannot be upgraded because of dependencies

So i'm trying to write a simple bash scripts that executes the init.d script, sleeps for a bit, inputs the username, returns, sleeping a bit, inputting the password - you'll get the flow.

like http://pastebin.com/qWHX7Di5

I've experimented with echo, but it doesent seem to work

This is for a rather legacy firewall i'm asked to keep connected.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `expect` instead of `bash`. You can still call it from within `bash` if you need to do other tasks as well.

In `expect`, the script would be something like the following (untested):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set username "username"
set password "password"

spawn /etc/init.d/openvpn.custom start
expect "Username:"
send "$username\r"
expect "Password:"
send "$password\r"
expect eof
```

You'd want to change the `expect "Username:"` & `expect "Password:"` lines to match the actual login prompts that are output by your `init.d` script.

See the [`expect` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) for further details.

Comment: proper solution indeed. And for @mvrasmussen : in the above script, change `expect "Username:"` to whatever the username prompt is for the device (ex: maybe it asks "Login:" or "login:" or "please enter your name:" : just change the "expect" line accordingly)

Comment: @OlivierDulac Thanks, I've updated the answer to clarify the need to customize the `expect` lines for the actual login prompts that are output by `openvpn.custom`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a [here-doc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document):

```
/path/to/init.d << END
$username
$password
END
```